# How do I expose port from Container to host?

Tags: docker

so I have my project which when installed on host makes login page available (via embedded Tomcat server) as

```
https://127.0.0.1:8443/
```

Now I installed this in ubuntu container and for installation the command I used was

```
docker run -it --name lp --dns=122.17.213.214 --dns=122.26.00.10 --dns-search=corp.sfc.san -p 8080:8443 -v ~/Downloads/logs:/logs -v ~/Downloads:/installers ubuntu /bin/bash
```

When I did that, I was not able to reach this on my host browser, what I tried was

```
https://my-docker-machine-ip:8443/ # I am using Mac OSX
```

Next, I thought to provide exact mapping and I tried

```
docker run -it --name lp --dns=122.17.213.214 --dns=122.26.00.10 --dns-search=corp.sfc.san -p 192.168.99.100:8443:8443 -v ~/Downloads/logs:/logs -v ~/Downloads:/installers ubuntu /bin/bash
```

and tried the same URL again, but no luck

What I see is `HTTP 404` from `Apache`. What am I missing?

However within the container, I see log that tells me that server is running

```
11 May 2016 22:19:19,166 [INFO ] [main] EmbeddedWebServer    | Starting tomcat server on port 8443 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is `-p hostPort:ContainerPort`. Your first example had the right syntax but the 'wrong' port (compared to what you were expecting).

Instead of:

```
docker run -it --name lp --dns=122.17.213.214 --dns=122.26.00.10 --dns-search=corp.sfc.san -p 8080:8443 -v ~/Downloads/logs:/logs -v ~/Downloads:/installers ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Use:

```
docker run -it --name lp --dns=122.17.213.214 --dns=122.26.00.10 --dns-search=corp.sfc.san -p 8443:8443 -v ~/Downloads/logs:/logs -v ~/Downloads:/installers ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Then

```
https://my-docker-machine-ip:8443/ # I am using Mac OSX
```

should work.

Comment: I see see the same issue